# Function availability

Tags: c++, arrays, search, c++14

Is there any inbuilt function available in C++ 14 to find if an element exists in an array?

The find() function is based on an iterator and used for vector. But what in the case of arrays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still use [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) from `<algorithm>` for that. An [input iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator) is a concept that is also modeled by by pointers, so you can use pointers as the arguments for [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) as follows:

```
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
  constexpr int N{10};

  int a[N] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
  return std::find(a, a + N, 5) != (a + N) ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the non member `begin()` and `end` from the STL:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
  int a[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
  auto it = std::find(std::begin(a), std::end(a), 3);

  if (it != std::end(a)) {
      // do stuff with the found element it
  }
}
```

It returns pointers to elements of the array, much like Ton van den Heuvel answer.

Also, don't forget [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), which is a lightweight wrapper arount a simple array:

```
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
  std::array a = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
  auto it = std::find(a.begin(), a.end(), 3);

  if (it != std::end(a)) {
      // do stuff with the found element it
  }
}
```